# How to remove the path from awk's input FILENAME variable - is basename available somehow?

Tags: bash, awk

The following command

```
gawk '{print $0, FILENAME}' input.txt > result.txt
```

where input.txt is:

```
FIXED3 LENGTH7      FILE FORMAT     00001
FIXED2 LENGTH8      FILE FORMAT     00002
FIXED2 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00003
FIXED1 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00004
```

Produces the following **Desired** result:

```
FIXED3 LENGTH7      FILE FORMAT     00001 input.txt
FIXED2 LENGTH8      FILE FORMAT     00002 input.txt
FIXED2 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00003 input.txt
FIXED1 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00004 input.txt
```

However if use a path to the file like below:

```
gawk '{print $0, FILENAME}' /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt > result.txt
```

Then FILENAME appended to each line also includes the path. This is what I want to correct I would like the same result as the first scenario above.

```
FIXED3 LENGTH7      FILE FORMAT     00001 /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
FIXED2 LENGTH8      FILE FORMAT     00002 /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
FIXED2 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00003 /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
FIXED1 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00004 /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split `FILENAME` with `/` to an array and output last element of array:

```
awk '{n=split(FILENAME,array,"/"); print $0, array[n]}' /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
$ gawk '{f=FILENAME; sub(/^.*\//,"",f); print $0, f}' ../here/file
FIXED3 LENGTH7      FILE FORMAT     00001 file
FIXED2 LENGTH8      FILE FORMAT     00002 file
FIXED2 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00003 file
FIXED1 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00004 file
```

Explained:

```
$ gawk '{
    f=FILENAME          # copy the filename to f
    sub(/^.*\//,"",f)   # process f instead, removeall from beginning to last /
    print $0, f         # etc. etc.
}' ../here/file
```

or since you did mention `gawk`:

```
$ gawk '{print $0, gensub(/^.*\//,"",1,FILENAME)}' ../here/file
```

Comment: This approach worked as well as Cyrus's.  Holding off on accepting an answer until I have experimented with each.  I upvoted each answer that did work so far.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. It will only run on first line to grab exact Input_file name and will NOT run on each line of file.

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(FILENAME~/\//){sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME)}} {print $0,FILENAME}' Input_file
```

***Possible benifits of this approach:***

1- NOT generating edited filename on each line, getting is on 1st line itself and simply prinintg in all other lines.

2- NO array/memory place holder created so this should be FAST on huge size file too.

3- Since I am simply printing it and not creating any additonal column with its filename values that will also save time during run of this code.

---

---

***EDIT:*** Just got another thought too, you could simply navigate to the new directory where Input_file present and could come back in code/one liner itself like example as follows. IMHO, I hope this will be FASTEST one among all other solutions mentioned here(since we are NOT doing any data manipulation here and moreover we are using same command which you used previously too :) )

```
cd  /cygdrive/c/dev/data/ && awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' input.txt && cd -
```

Speciality of this command would be it will come back to your original directory where you are running the code so you wil lnever feel like you navigated anywhere :)

Comment: @anubhava, Hi Anubhava sir, since you are expert(out of all GEMS on SO) on BASH and awk, my thinking is my EDIT solution I believe should be good and fast compare to splitting FILENAME or creating an array, would like to know your views on same, whenever you have time please. Will be grateful to you sir, if you could let me know your views on this one.

Answer (score 1):

A little tweak for efficiency and for conciseness:

```
gawk 'FNR==1{f=gensub(".*/","",1,FILENAME)} $(NF+1)=f'
```

Only extract the `filename` ( `f` here ) once from each file, by executing that part at first line.
And since `FILENAME` won't be empty, so just append it to the line, the `{print $0}` will be implied.

However, that will change output separator if it's not a single space.
Use below one if that's not what you wanted:

```
gawk 'FNR==1{f=gensub(".*/","",1,FILENAME)}{print $0 OFS f}'
```

Comment: The second variation (with $0 OFS f) of your answer is the one that works as expected on my fixed width file format.

Comment: @Brian  Different situations, different needs. Glad to know it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` using `/` as separator

```
gawk -F"/"  ' { printf("%s ",$0) ; $0=FILENAME } { print $NF } ' /home/full/path/input.txt
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
FIXED3 LENGTH7      FILE FORMAT     00001
FIXED2 LENGTH8      FILE FORMAT     00002
FIXED2 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00003
FIXED1 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00004

$ gawk -F"/"  ' { printf("%s ",$0) ; $0=FILENAME } { print $NF } ' /cygdrive/c/dev/data/input.txt
FIXED3 LENGTH7      FILE FORMAT     00001 input.txt
FIXED2 LENGTH8      FILE FORMAT     00002 input.txt
FIXED2 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00003 input.txt
FIXED1 LENGTH20     FILE FORMAT     00004 input.txt

$
```